# Change value inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'd like to change the values of an array.

Currently my array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+Yes
            [1] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+N/A
            [2] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+No
        )

)
```

I want to remove everything before the + symbol, so in the end the new array will looke like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yes
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => No
        )

)
```

This is my code:

```
        $new_array = array();

        foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {

            $split = explode("+", $value[0]);               
            $new_array[] = $split[1];   

        }
```

Hoping that it would worked, but when I check the new array, it only shows one value.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Yes
)
```

Any help in putting me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check it:

```
<?php
$array[0][0] = '12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+Yes';
$array[0][1] = '12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+N/A';
$array[0][2] = '112-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+No';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);

$new_array = array();

foreach( $array[0] as $key => $value ) {

    $split = explode("+", $value);
    $new_array[] = $split[1];

}
print_r($new_array);

echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was late) But still I prescribed the code for the full test.

Comment: I totally overlooked that it should've been `$array[0]`. Thank you!

Comment: When you test your code, you might spend a little more time, but it's the right thing to do. I removed my untested answer and support yours. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try This this work even if you have multiple key in the original array `$original_array[0]`, `$original_array[1]` ... :

```
$original_array[0] = [
    0 => '12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+Yes',
    1 => '12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+N/A',
    2 => '12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+No'
];
print_r($original_array); 

$new_array = [];
foreach ($original_array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $index => $val) {
        $split = explode("+", $val);
        $new_array[$key][] = $split[1];
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Example :
`Original array`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+Yes
            [1] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+N/A
            [2] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+No
        ),
   [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+Yes
            [1] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+N/A
            [2] => 12-Multi_select-customfield-retina-ready+No
        )
)
```

`New Array`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yes
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => No
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Yes
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => No
        )
)
```